# Accurately tracking Angular's active/done promises invoked by $q.defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, profiling, promise, angular-promise

For my angular application, i'm trying to track how many promises have been processed and how many still need processing.

My code decorates $q with wrapper methods that update a simple counter whenever an operation is started and whenever one is finished, seems simple:

```
  angular.module('DuckieTV',[])
  .config(function($provide) {
  var count = window.promiseStats = { 
    open: 0,
    done: 0 
  };
  $provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate) {

    function decorate(p) {
      p._then = p.then;
      p.then = function(thenFn, errFn, notifyFn) {
       count.open++;
       return p._then(function() { 
            count.done++;
            if(thenFn) return thenFn.apply(this,arguments)
        }, function() {
          count.done++;
          if(errFn) return errFn.apply(this,arguments)
        }, notifyFn);
      };

      p._finally = p.finally;
      p.finally = function(callback) {
        count.done++;
        p._finally(callback)
      }

      p._catch = p.catch;
      p.catch = function(callback) {
        count.done++;
        p._catch(callback)
      }
      return p;
    }

    var d = $delegate.defer;
    $delegate.defer = function() {
      var deferred = d();
      decorate(deferred.promise);
      return deferred;
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
})
```

The fun begins when I'm noticing a discrepancy between started/finished promises. After just a few minutes of performing lots of deferred operations it can become a > 15% percentage overall.

Example console output:

```
promiseStats
Object {open: 99, done: 95}
Math.floor(promiseStats.done / promiseStats.open * 100);
94
```

after some work (import operations)

```
promiseStats;
Object {open: 185, done: 172}
Math.floor(promiseStats.done / promiseStats.open * 100);
92
```

My actual question: Can anyone tell me if i'm missing something with this implementation?

As far as I know, I haven't missed optional implementations and all the promises that i'm firing via .then are properly coded

Comment: Thanks @bergi, that could be an interesting one.

Comment: I'll make that into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if i'm missing something with this implementation?

I can see two issues with your implementation:

- Your decorated `catch` and `invoke` methods only ever increase the `done` count, never the `open` one. Since you not seeing this, I'd guess that you haven't used either in your code.
- By introducing an `onfail` handler to every `.then()` call, you implicitly *catch all errors* and severely [hurt control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). You might be able to fix this by appending the following line to your handler code:

  ```
   …
   else throw arguments[0];
  ```

> I'm noticing a discrepancy between started/finished promises

I don't think this is caused by your implementation of the counters. Rather you *really* have some ever-pending promises in your code; i.e. deferreds that are never resolved. This for example might be caused by mistakes in code that uses the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

> My code decorates `$q` with wrapper methods that update a simple counter whenever an operation is started and whenever one is finished, seems simple:

In fact, it updates a counter whenever a *listener is attached*, i.e. a `then`/`catch`/`finally` method is called. I'd propose a simpler implementation, that counts on *creation* and doesn't even need to overwrite the methods:

```
$provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate) {
    var defer = $delegate.defer;
    $delegate.defer = function() {
        var deferred = defer();
        count.open++;
        deferred.promise.finally(function() {
            count.done++;
        });
        return deferred;
    };
    return $delegate;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. This is what I came to StackOverflow for.

I'm definitely guilty of abusing the deferred antipattern and will fix this asap :)

Comment: So it was really responsible for the pending promises? Thanks for the confirmation, it was only a suspicion of mine that such could happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

The plot thickens.

I've been profiling and tracing code based upon the excellent code by @Bergi and noticed that consistently promise #31 was left open, so I added a debug statement right there:

```
.config(function($provide) {
    var count = window.promiseStats = {
        open: 0,
        done: 0,
        promises: {}
    };
    $provide.decorator('$q', function($delegate) {


    var defer = $delegate.defer;
        $delegate.defer = function() {

            count.open++;
            var traceId = count.open;
            if(traceId == 31) { 
                debugger;
            }
            var deferred = count.promises[traceId] = defer();
            console.timeline('promise ' +traceId);
            console.profile('promise '+traceId);

            deferred.promise.finally(function() {
                count.done++;
                console.timelineEnd('promise ' +traceId);
                console.profileEnd('promise '+traceId);
                delete count.promises[traceId];    
            });
            return deferred;
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
})
```

This dropped me directly inside an angular-core template request that seems to have a different kind of promise handling.

[image]

I'm still trying to assess wether or not this is a problem. as it does seem to unregister with some specialized code.

Comment: Well, [there we've got them](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9ba24c54d60e643b1450cc5cfa8f990bd524c130/src/ng/http.js#L965-989)! In the case that `cachedResp` is `return`ed, there is indeed a `deferred` constructed that is never resolved. It's not really a problem (since no one *expects* the `deferred.promise` to resolve in that case), but it looks like unclean coding.